# Which countries in the world remain neutral in the Ukraine conflict?

Tags: russian-federation, international-relations, armed-conflict, ukraine, country-neutrality

Which countries are staying neutral in the war against Ukraine?

Comment: Have you tried searching for an answer to that question, for example on Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reactions_to_the_2022_Russian_invasion_of_Ukraine and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reactions_to_the_2022_Russian_invasion_of_Ukraine#/media/File:International_reactions_to_the_2022_Russian_invasion_of_Ukraine.svg?

Comment: The definition of the term "neutral" is subject to debates, too. Not every state has the same understanding of this term, nor every politician within a state.

Comment: Does opposing sanctions constitute neutrality? Does calling for peace or refusing to send soldiers to fight constitute neutrality? What about making a vague condemnation of war following the invasion without specifically condemning either side? Or are you looking for countries that abstained in UN votes?

Answer (score 11):

We could infer the stance of various countries by how they voted on the [UN resolution from March 2nd 2022 to condemn the aggression against Ukraine](https://news.un.org/en/story/2022/03/1113152).

These countries voted against the resolution, implying that they support the invasion:

- Belarus
- North Korea
- Eritrea [[related question](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/71325/what-reasoning-did-eritrea-provide-for-its-vote-on-the-un-resolution-against-the)]
- Russia
- Syria

These 35 countries abstained, which should be interpreted as having a neutral stance on the conflict:

- Algeria
- Angola
- Armenia
- Bangladesh
- Bolivia
- Burundi
- Central African Republic
- China
- Congo
- Cuba
- El Salvador
- Equatorial Guinea
- India [[related question](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/71099/why-has-india-abstained-on-the-unsc-resolution-on-russia-in-ukraine)]
- Iran
- Iraq
- Kazakhstan
- Kyrgyzstan
- Laos
- Madagascar
- Mali
- Mongolia
- Mozambique
- Namibia
- Nicaragua
- Pakistan
- Senegal
- South Africa
- South Sudan
- Sri Lanka
- Sudan
- Tajikistan
- Uganda
- Tanzania
- Vietnam
- Zimbabwe

These countries did not participate in the vote, which means they refused to make a clear statement regarding where they stand on the issue:

- Azerbaijan
- Burkina Faso
- Cameroon
- Eswatini
- Ethiopia
- Guinea
- Guinea-Bissau
- Morocco
- Togo
- Turkmenistan
- Uzbekistan

Venezuela wasn't allowed to participate in the vote due to their voting rights being suspended at the time.

The 141 other UN member states voted for the resolution.

Comment: Most of the middle east countries are missing from the list, any explanation?

Comment: @r13 There are several middle-eastern countries on the list. Those which are missing are obviously among the 141 which voted for the resolution. When you would like to know the individual reasons of any particular country, please post a new question like people did for India and Eritrea.

Comment: Depending on your definition of "Neutral" Israel. It has an arrangement of sorts with Russia allow it limited access to Syrian airspace to bomb targets that it feels threaten its security, and has limited its response to Russian actions accordingly.

Comment: @Philipp "Those which are missing are obviously among the 141 which voted for the resolution.", like Saudi Arabia and UAE (two US allies)? I made my comment because you didn't bother to verify the data you copied and posted, which may contain many more mistakes. Also, where is the reference or source of the data?